# Case-by-case Coffee-script push method

Tags: coffeescript

When I push the index of itemList in list 'a'.
Right in for loop, it works fine.
But when I push the index in if statement, it doesn't work.
I don't know what's secret exists behind the coffee-script engine.

```
a=[]
for item, index of itemList
    a.push(index)
    if item.isExchanged is true
        a.push(index)
```

Comment: What does `itemList` look like? If it is (as its name suggests) an array then you're using the wrong type of loop for it. What do you expect `a` too look like after the loop and what does it really look like?

Comment: itemList looks like `[obj,obj,obj,....obj]` I just to want push an object to an new array `a`.

Comment: If `itemList` is an array then you want `for item, index in itemList`, `for ... of` is for iterating over objects, you use `for ... in` for arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Some guesses:

```
for item, index of itemList
```

So, `item` takes in its turn each property name/array index. So how could `item.isExchanged` be true:

```
    if item.isExchanged is true
    #  ^^^^
    # string object
```

Don't you have simply swapped item <-> index:

```
for index, item of itemList
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will iterate through your object/dictionary key value pairs.

In the other hand, if `itemList` is an *array* you should write:

```
for item, index in itemList
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^
```

Notice that `item` and `index` are in the same order as in our original question. But I used the keyword `in` there.

Comment: I'll try this. And add a comment later. Thanks!

Comment: Or better, use `for ... in` instead of `for ... of`.

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you for your comment. For some reason, I thought the OP wanted to iterate through some kind of "dictionary". If `itemList` is a plain array, ̀for ... in ...` is probably the required syntax. I've modified my answer accordingly.